# How to use Enzyme Shallow with Jest snapshots

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to use [shallow](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/shallow.md) from [enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme) and also use [snapshots](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/snapshot-testing.html) from [jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/) together.

The problem I'm facing is that I need to change something from the state using `setState()` from [enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/blob/master/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/setState.md) and then match the result with the snapshot.

See the code of my component:

```
....

getPrevProduct = () => {
  const key = this.state.indexCurrent > 0 &&
   this.productsKeys[this.state.indexCurrent - 1];

  let product = null;

  if (key) {
    product = this.props.products[key];
  }

  return product;
}

renderPrev = () => this.getPrevProduct() && <PrevButton />;

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      ...
      {this.renderPrev()}
      ...
    <div>
  )
}
```

The previous code checks if the product, passed from props in the currentIndex, exists.

That's why I need Enzyme to change the state. Then, if it matches, `<PrevButton />` has to be rendered.

This test is when I want to match the component with the snapshot:

```
const nextProps = {
  products: {
    test: 'test'
  }
};

const tree = create(<Component nextProps={nextProps} />).toJSON();

expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
```

But I need to change the state. How I can do that? This doesn't work:

```
it('should render component with prev button', () => {
  const nextProps = {
    products: {
      test: 'test'
    }
  };
  const instance = shallow(<Component nextProps={nextProps} />).instance()

  instance.setState({
    indexCurrent: 1
  });

  const tree = create(<Component nextProps={nextProps} />).toJSON();

  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

I also tried to save the declaration of the component into a variable like the next uncompleted code and use it in `shallow` and `create`:

```
const component = <Component nextProps={nextProps} />;

 shallow(component).instance()).instance()
 create(component).toJSON()`
```

I also tried with no luck [enzyme-to-json](https://github.com/adriantoine/enzyme-to-json).

What would you do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trial and error, I found that enzyme has a method, not documented (or I didn't find it) called `getRenderOutput`.

That method return the component in JSON format so I can do that:

```
it('should render component with prev button', () => {
  const nextProps = {
    products: {
      test: 'test'
    }
  };
  const render = shallow(mockComponent(nextProps))
  const instance = render.instance();

  instance.setState({
    indexCurrent: 1
  });

  const tree = render.renderer.getRenderOutput();

  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

That's how I can use snapshots from Jest with enzyme.

The only problem with `getRenderOutput` is that if I put a console log, it will be printed twice. That's because `instance()` and `getRenderOutput()`, both fires the test.

This is the output of the snapshot:

```
exports[`ProductNavigator should render component with prev button 1`] = `
  <div>
    <FloatingActionButton
      className="NavigatorButton left"
      onTouchTap={[Function]}
      secondary={true}
    >
      <KeyboardArrowLeft />
    </FloatingActionButton>
  </div>
`;
```

If someone knows a better way to do that, please, add a comment.

Thanks!

Comment: Use 'enzyme-json'. Then you can convert it to json similar to shallow(<Comp>).toJson....

Comment: Yes, I tried, as I said in my question, but I had this error:
`Cannot find module 'enzyme/build/RSTTraversal' from 'shallow.js'`
and I didn't find a solution with that

Comment: make sure to install https://github.com/adriantoine/enzyme-to-json#install

Comment: yes, I followed those instructions and nothing. Maybe was something about my configuration. I need time to look at it much better.

Comment: hi @AlbertOlivé did u get it working ? Cannot find module 'enzyme/build/RSTTraversal' from 'shallow.js' .  I'm also getting the same error !

Comment: See my answer. I fixed with that

Answer (score 7):

Probably, its not the way `enzyme-to-json` is supposed to be used. Try this way :

```
import { shallowToJson  } from 'enzyme-to-json';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
```

and then in your test :

```
const wrapper = shallow(<Component />);
expect(shallowToJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
```

Answer (score 5):

Install `enzyme-to-json`

```
npm install --save-dev enzyme-to-json
```

Update your jest config:

```
"jest": {
  "snapshotSerializers": [
    "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
  ]
}
```

Test

```
it('works', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />)
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

Original: https://devhints.io/enzyme#installing