# Result of my Enzyme snapshot test is empty

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am still new to Jest Enzyme tests in React, my snapshot test results in an empty snap.

I have the following test code:

```
import React from 'react';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import { shallow, configure } from 'enzyme';

import { Button } from '../src/components/common/Button/Button';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('Button', () => {
  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(Button).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should render correctly', () => {
    const tree = shallow(<Button />);
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

My snapshot result:

```
exports[`Button should render correctly 1`] = `ShallowWrapper {}`;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't you need e.g. `shallowToJson`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/47347195/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes ended up using that to fix it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution

```
import React from 'react';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import { configure, mount } from 'enzyme';
import { shallowToJson } from 'enzyme-to-json';

import { Button } from '../src/components/common/Button/Button';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

describe('Button', () => {
  it('should be defined', () => {
    expect(Button).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('should render correctly', () => {
    const tree = mount(<Button />);
    expect(shallowToJson(tree)).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```